# How to implement a scheduled job as a microservice

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I have a Spring Boot application which provides REST API for Angular web interface.

There is also a scheduled job that is currently in this Spring Boot application. The job is to fill in the database with some enities, let's say books (they are taken from an external source, more specifically, from a web-site). I want to place this job into a separate microservice.

The question is whether the microservice should work directly with the shared database or access the main application via REST. In the first case some (if not the all) models and services will be shared, it doesn't look good. But in the second case each access to database will go through the first application. Is that ok?

Comment: What is the rationale behind creating a separate microservice? Does those entities not belong to the scope of the existing microservice?

Comment: No, they do belong to the same scope. Just want to try the microservice architecture and see when it can simplify the application

Answer (score 5):

Check out [SOLID](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/solid-design-microservices) design principle.

**S** - is for `Single Responsibility`

There's also a pattern in microservice architecture with the very same name: [Single Responsibility Principle](https://howtodoinjava.com/microservices/microservices-definition-principles-benefits/)

> The single responsibility principle is one of the principles defined
>   as part of the SOLID design pattern. It implies that a unit, either a
>   class, a function, or a microservice, should have one and only one
>   responsibility.
>
> At no point in time, one microservice should have more than one
>   responsibility.

You should decide which microservice should do what based on your application design, you definitely know it better than we do.

But having read your description I'd suggest the following:

- your current `database-microservice` should be connected to DB and accept HTTP requests to save books in the database;
- your new `cronjob-microservice` should start the job in time, get books from the website and send HTTP request to the `database-microservice`, hence it shouldn't be connected to the database.

Comment: I also tend to this option

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use a queue like ActiveMQ instead of REST.

The `cronjob-service` fetches the books and validates the data for example. 
You can than store the data somewhere in file format like csv. It could be stored on a S3 Bucket on AWS or something like that. The `cronjob-service` than sends a refrence to that file via the queue and the `database-service` fetches the data and stores it.

The advantage over REST is, that a task can not be lost. If you're `database-service` is down or occupied for some reason, a REST request would return 404 and you have to implement a failsafe against it. With a queue, the task is stored within the queue. Even if a `database-service` instance starts handling the task and fails for some reason, the task is still in the queue and another `database-service` instance can pick it up and handle it.